# tool for checking paths executed during running a program in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am wondering is there any plugin for eclipse to see the paths are executed in run time, i.e. I want to know which classes or packages are not reached in tun time? I do not want to debug my code I just want to see which packages or classes are not hinted or vice versa

Comment: Are you looking for the classes that are not on the running plugin's class path?

Answer (score 0):

Install [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/), a code coverage tool for Eclipse. It will tell you which lines, methods and classes have been covered during a run and which have not.

Additionally, the [Useless Code Detector](http://www.ucdetector.org/) plugin can tell you which of your code cannot even be reached (e.g. finding public methods which are not called from anywhere). This is done without execution by static code analysis.